# ClickHouse EmbeddedRocksDB full scan on range query

Tags: clickhouse, rocksdb

I try to use EmbeddedRocksDB engine in ClickHouse and I can't understand why EmbeddedRocksDB does full scan on range query.

**To reproduce**

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table
(
    key  String,
    value String
) ENGINE EmbeddedRocksDB PRIMARY KEY key;

INSERT INTO sample_table SELECT
    concat(prefix, 'T', timestamp),
    value
FROM
(
    SELECT
        leftPad(toString(toUInt32(randUniform(1, 1000000))), 7, '0') AS prefix,
        toString(toUInt32(randUniform(1640984400, 1672434000))) AS timestamp,
        generateUUIDv4() AS value
    FROM numbers(100000000)
);
```

I do range query:

```
chdb1 :) select * from sample_table where key between '0000001T1644717403' and '0000001T1648650040'

SELECT *
FROM sample_table
WHERE (key >= '0000001T1644717403') AND (key <= '0000001T1648650040')

Query id: ea9cf222-f0ab-467e-9108-49383aeb01b4

┌─key────────────────┬─value────────────────────────────────┐
│ 0000001T1644717403 │ c1b6d265-88f8-482d-838c-6e063e2f1636 │
│ 0000001T1644796827 │ 05ff0d95-d731-43b8-b1ee-b8a070f77083 │
│ 0000001T1644821785 │ bb8ae394-9bab-4d2c-ab7b-54f56843e449 │
│ 0000001T1645253016 │ cfbab6f3-4f13-4efa-8312-3fcc5a42bd59 │
│ 0000001T1645764765 │ 0aad9a20-2a13-4d68-8b47-7a49bff00eba │
│ 0000001T1645913244 │ 1e231b76-c6a9-4ffa-8736-4294508c280e │
│ 0000001T1646308114 │ d142cce3-e842-4404-9d99-077e94232e9e │
│ 0000001T1647627659 │ 6f63308e-6323-42d0-99bb-d7558c8f25b5 │
│ 0000001T1647653887 │ 1969f67e-897a-4d9a-90c8-102f59d86dfa │
│ 0000001T1647708677 │ a317c3ca-54ec-41bf-ab45-3d1a3a408eed │
│ 0000001T1648292194 │ 34276809-7bcf-40c9-9366-95ac15a94e9b │
│ 0000001T1648352410 │ 3512e343-1664-4405-8016-5e881da55dc3 │
│ 0000001T1648650040 │ 1163f61c-9e7f-493a-a5fc-61cc2e3b2211 │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘

13 rows in set. Elapsed: 57.785 sec. Processed 100.00 million rows, 6.30 GB (1.73 million rows/s., 109.03 MB/s.)
```

The 13 rows are returned very fast, but it continue scan all keys.
How It can be fixed?